# FatalErrorException Call to a member function except() on null

Tags: php, laravel

I am building a QA, and when i try to show a question, I am getting this error. `FatalErrorException Call to a member function except() on null in web.php line 10`

Here is the web.php code

```
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::resource('questions', 'QuestionsController')->except('show');
Route::get('/questions/{slug}', 'QuestionsController@show')->name('questions.show');
```

in the `QuestionsController.php` file the `show` function is

```
 public function show(Question $question)
    {
        $question->increment('views');
        return view('questions.show', compact('question'));
    }
```

in addition, here is the view part when the question is displayed

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
        <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
            <h>{{ $question->title }} </h1>
                <div class="ml-auto">
                    <a href="{{ route('questions.index') }}" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Back to all Questions</a>
                </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="card-body">
        {{ !! $question->body_html !! }}
    </div>
</div>
```

so if my question is clear, how can I get rid of this error? Thank you for your help, Sirs!

Comment: the show method you describe after resource is the same as in the resource why you redefine it.

Comment: I wanted to use a different method when the route is like this `Route::get('/questions/{slug}', 'QuestionsController@show')->name('questions.show');`

Comment: Which laravel version are you using?

Comment: And `except(['show'])` should be like this.

Comment: I am using `Laravel Framework 5.4.36` and `except(['show'])` <---has not solved the error...is there any other way?

Comment: @Amit Senjaliya given the another way of doing this.

Comment: @DhavalPurohit Ok But that is not working right?

Comment: @AmitSenjaliya It is working perfectly in my laravel 5.8

Answer (score 2):

Try to below code:

```
Route::resource('questions', 'QuestionsController', ['except' => ['show']]);
```

Answer (score 0):

i think so it is because you should use find() or something elese first.
for example you should find question **by id** or slug or anything, then you can increment the field you want.
for example:

```
$question = Question::find(5)->increment('views');
```

or

```
$question = Question::where('url', '=', 'some value')->increment('views');
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct your route. by following this sample code. Here is the official document you can check it [https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/controllers#resource-controllers]

```
Route::resource('questions', 'QuestionsController')->except(['show']);
Route::get('/questions/{slug}', 'QuestionsController@show')->name('questions.show');
```